# Can CryptoKit be used with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello I have an Objective-C project and I want to start using Apple's CryptoKit framework. Is this possible?

Comment: CryptoKit is Swift only. The best you would be able to do is write Objective-C wrappers that perform the specific CryptoKit functions you need.

Comment: I've used it very recently, no problem, in an Objective-C only project. I only needed a few of the ```CommonCrypto``` functions and after adding ```CryptoKit``` as framework and importing ```<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>``` as header could use it no problem. I think it depends - what specifically are you interested in using?

Answer (score 1):

Late to answer, but IMHO it is easiest to create a Swift Static Library or a Swift Framework w/ Apple's CryptoKit (dependency) and link it to your obj-c project. Then of course you'd import the Swift Static Lib/Framework headers into your Obj-C Class.

[image: Framework in Xcode]

Be sure to prefix your Swift functions with `@objc open` for both your class and functions.

I'd encourage you to use delegates, maybe some singleton pattern in your Swift CryptoKit Wrapper.

You can link your Swift Framework into your obj-c classes with a readonly property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CryptoKitWrapper *wrapper;
```

Since in the Swift Wrapper Class you have them set as open/obj-c prefix the funcs are exposed.

As a pseudo example, here is a Swift Func, and obj-c calling it.

Obj-c:

```
- (NSData *) hashSHA256: (NSData *) data
{
    return [_wrapper SHA256hashWithData:data];
}
```

Swift class/func:

```
@objc open class CryptoKitWrapper: NSObject  {
    public static let shared = CryptoKitWrapper()
    public var delegate:CryptoKitWrapperProtocol?
    
    @objc open func SHA256hash(data: Data) -> Data {
        let digest = SHA256.hash(data: data)
        CryptoKitWrapper.shared.delegate?.didCallSHA256Hash()
        return Data(digest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
#include<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Worked for me in straight C and, since Objective C is a strict superset, it should work.

I couldn't find any direct documentation, but the header files themselves specify the parameters.

This is not CryptoKit, but unless you have an edge case it will work and is Apple supplied as opposed to openssl or libressl. Since OP mentioned it, I thought that was a reason for giving commoncrypto as an alternative. The actual implementation of the algorithms doesn't differ in any significant way for most cases.

Comment: That would work, but it is a different library from CryptoKit.

Comment: `CommonCrypto.h` is not `CryptoKit`. They are completely different frameworks and APIs.

Comment: See the answer above, @skaak reports using these headers and adding CryptoKit as a framework. I'm aware they are different, but they aren't *that* different and the calls may be identical.

Comment: In order to say the calls may be identical, you would need to be able to use these frameworks as drop-in replacements of each other to an extent, but that is largely not the case. CryptoKit being higher level has a simpler API and supports fewer crypto algorithms than CommonCrypto. Which funnily enough, many algorithms  supported by CryptoKit are not in CommonCrypto (like ChaChaPoly and AES-GCM, though supposedly AES-GCM is a private API in CommonCrypto).